# Changing between 2 chart every 10 seconds using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, charts, carousel

I have 2 charts(line and bar chart) and I want to change between them every 10 seconds or so. I tried Bootstrap [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) but it doesn't seems to work when I replace the image src with the id of my chart. The id for those 2 charts are:

```
<div id="SummaryChart"></div>
<div id="DailyBarChart"></div>
```

Is there a way I could make it work? Thanks!

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<?php include 'linechart.php'; ?>
    <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    </head>

<body>


<div class="cycle-slideshow">
   <div id="PieChart"></div>
   <div id="DailyBarChart"></div>
</div>

        <!-- end page-wrapper -->

    <!-- end wrapper -->

    <!-- Core Scripts - Include with every page -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/scripts/zingchart-html5-min.js"></script>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

It seems like it could only work on images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery.Cycle2, you could do it this way :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>

<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-timeout="10000" data-cycle-slides="> div">
    <div id="SummaryChart"></div>
    <div id="DailyBarChart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: when I used this method it will show 2 chart at once on the page.

Comment: I forgot "http://" in the second line. Now it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/w632rqb8/
Does it?